# How to INSERT new row and UPDATE old row value?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert a new row to *table* with my PHP form input values

`$_POST['bill_amount']`, `$_POST['paid_amount']` and `$_POST['due_amount']`

as well as update the *due_amount* column of the second last row with value "0".

Afterwards, I'd like to select and *echo* the values of the last row (the newly inserted row).

My PHP code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED); ?>

<body>

    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    ?>

    <?php
        include 'dbconnection.php';
        $ba = $_POST['bill_amount'];
        $pa = $_POST['paid_amount'];
        $da = $_POST['due_amount']
        $sql = "INSERT into table(bill_amount,paid_amount,due_amount)
              values ('$ba','$pa','$da')";
             "UPDATE table SET due_amount='0' ORDER BY bill_id DESC LIMIT 1,1";

        if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
            die('Error:' . mysql_error());
        }

        echo "Here's the newly inserted record:";
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY bill_id DESC LIMIT 1");  

        echo "<table>
                <tr>
                   <th>Bill ID</th>
                   <th>Bill Amount</th>
                   <th>Paid Amount</th>    
                   <th>Due Amount</th>
                </tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['bill_id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['bill_amount'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['paid_amount'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['due_amount'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    ?>

    <HTML>

    <?php
        }
        else {
            echo "session expired";
        }
    ?>

    </body>
</html>

<?PHP
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The problem with my PHP code is that it successfully inserts a new row to *table*, but doesn't update the *due_amount* column of the second last row with the value "0"

The first view of *table* :
(please note that "bill_id" is `auto increment primary key`) :

```
       +------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+  
       | bill_id    | bill_amount | paid_amount   | due_amount    | 
       +------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
       | 1          | 200         | 100           | 100           |
       +------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

The View of *table* after executing my PHP code:

```
       +------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+  
       | bill_id    | bill_amount | paid_amount   | due_amount    | 
       +------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
       | 1          | 200         | 100           | 100           |
       +------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
       | 2          | 300         | 100           | 200           |
       +------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

The View of *table* I would like to have after executing my PHP code:

```
       +------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+  
       | bill_id    | bill_amount | paid_amount   | due_amount    | 
       +------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
       | 1          | 200         | 100           | 0             |
       +------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
       | 2          | 300         | 100           | 200           |
       +------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: depending on your mysql server you need to either seperate the two queries (insert and update) with a `;` (inside the sql-string) or even make two seperate queries of it.

Comment: a part of your problem is, that the update statement never makes it into the sql-string (because of the `;` outside of the string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to seperate your queries like so:

```
 <?php 
 // ....
 $sql = "INSERT into table(bill_amount,paid_amount,due_amount)
          values ('$ba','$pa','$da')";

 $sql_update = "UPDATE table SET due_amount='0' ORDER BY bill_id DESC LIMIT 1,1";

 if(!mysql_query($sql))
 {
   die('Error:' . mysql_error());
 }

 if(!mysql_query($sql_update))
 {
   die('Error:' . mysql_error());
 }
 /....
 ?>
```

Apart from that you're vulnerable to **sql-injection**.
Please read about prepared statement and how to avoid sql-injection!

Answer (score 0):

You need get the ID of record before the INSERT.

Another solution can be exclude the new generated row with last_insert_id() and omit this Id from your UPDATE.

Some like this:

```
 $sql = "INSERT into table(bill_amount,paid_amount,due_amount) values ('$ba','$pa','$da');
         UPDATE table SET due_amount='0'  WHERE bill_id != LAST_INSERT_ID() ORDER BY bill_id DESC LIMIT 1,1;";
```

Take care with:

- SQL Injection.
- Your code can be problematic with concerrencies.

Comment: will not work if he only got 1 entry before that (and 2 after the insert).